# iOS 9 - Location update getting error didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Tags: objective-c, ios8, cllocationmanager, ios9

I am using following code to update location - it works fine below iOS 9 but in iOS 9 getting error -

```
   locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   [locationManager setDelegate:self];
   [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
   [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];

   if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
      [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

 // tried this also - 
      /* if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
  locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;}*/
       [locationManager requestLocation];
```

> didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Also done change in `plist` file -

[image]

Anyone can suggest what I am missing ?

Comment: please check: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808192/allowsbackgroundlocationupdates-in-cllocationmanager-in-ios9

Comment: @San007 Do u find any solution  for this. I'm getting this problem in iPads only, its working in iPhone.

Comment: I am also facing  d same problem,,,did u find d solution

Answer (score 2):

This error was also rising for me when location requirement keys are not added to Info.plist.

Check if you have one of these keys (with Bool values) in your Info.plist:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription 
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

- Please reset your network settings
- Reset your location services
- Check that the WiFi or 3G work
- Another is when Scheme/Edit Scheme/Options/Allow Location Simulation checked but don't have a default location set.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Pasha_Molodkin, I would suggest that you try this out (common bug when no default location provided) :

[my answer to a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887820/4887400)

In short :

- Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Options -> Allow Location Simulation must be checked and try providing a default location, don't leave it set to "none"