# didUpdateLocations is not called in ios 9.3.2

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

didUpdateLocations is never called, instead didFailWithError is called with denied code `kCLErrorDenied`.
Here are the things that i did:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import CoreLocation;

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {

        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(nonnull NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations

{

    NSLog(@"update");

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(nonnull NSError *)error

{

    NSLog(@"error");
}

@end
```

Inserted `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to the info.plist of the app. Enabled Background Modes in Capabilities with Location updates selected. Get help from the very famous blog [post](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/). I receive Location Access Request popup and allow the app to access location.

But i couldnt managed to get location updates. It works in IPAD with IOS 8 but not work at ipad with IOS version 9.3.2. How can i make location updates work in IOS 9.3.2?

Comment: What error it gives in `didFailWithError`?

Comment: @Ronak Chaniyara Updated the question. I get kCLErrorDenied (Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 “(null)”)

Answer (score 0):

trying following thing may resolve your issue:

- go to settings and reset your location services
- reset your network settings
- restarting the simulator

also, if you have Scheme/Edit Scheme/Options/Allow Location Simulation checked but don't have a default location set.

Add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your plist as type string if using Always authorization. Also, do the same for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` same way if using WhenInUse authorization.

For detail check answers here:

[didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldn-t-be)

and [IOS 9 Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543754/ios-9-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-null)

Comment: I am using a real device for debugging. It works with Allow Location Simulation on simulator but not in the real device. I added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription  and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to plist as mentioned in my question.  I read nearly every stackoverflow post, but couldnt find a solution. I applied the things you said but not working.