# Cant get current location in iPhone X Swift

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, cllocationmanager, iphone-x

I am trying to get my current location. My GPS is working and getting current location in all iOS devices expect iPhone X?
Why I am not getting current location in iPhone X only?
I am using iPhone X simulator for testing.Is it simulator bug or do I have to make any change in my code?

Here is my code.
Hope you understand my problem. Thanks in advance.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>we want to know where you are!</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>we want to get your location</string>


extension NotificationCenterViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
      if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
          locationManager.requestLocation()
      }
   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

      let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
      locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

      let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
      let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
      // Why I am getting this error in only in iPhone X only.
      print("error:: (error)")
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543754/ios-9-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-null

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it didn't work.My App is working in all devices and simulator of all iOS version expect iPhone X.What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `locationManager.startLocationUpdates()` function anywhere in your code?
If not, then add this line where you have allocated location manager or called it in `didChangeAuthorization` when you get `.authorizedWhenInUse` status.

It is required to call `locationManager.startLocationUpdates()` to get location updated data.

Comment: What was that method? 
Value of type 'CLLocationManager' has no member 'startLocationUpdates'

,  do you mean locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()?

Comment: Yes, locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() this method need to call.

Comment: I got the problem.I was denied location permission.so that i got all of this issues.can we programmatically ask for location permission if user denied permission first?

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem, but solution was very easy, delete your app from simulator iPhone X and rewrite again.

Comment: Thanks bro.I find the issue.I was denied location permission first.so that i got all of this issues.