# Core Location not working in simulator Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, core-location

I have the following code:

```
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, NetworkingDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

and then later:

```
 locationManager.delegate = self
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
 locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
 locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

and then I implement the delegate methods lower in the VC

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        for currentLocation in locations{
            print("\(index)\(currentLocation)")
        }
        print("Did Location Delegate get called?")
        let location: CLLocation = locations.first as! CLLocation
        print(location)
        self.lat = String(format: "%f", location.coordinate.latitude)
        self.long = String(format: "%f", location.coordinate.longitude)
        }
```

In build phases, "Link Binary With Libraries" has CoreLocation.framework selected.

The proper privacy in plist is present: Privacy - Location Usage Description as is Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description.

The location is still not being gotten. I am using simulator in Xcode 9.4.1 targeting iOS 11. What am I missing here?

Comment: **YOU MUST TURN ON LOC. IN XCODE SIMULATOR OPTIONS!!** so annoying.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887820/294884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)` is years out of date. Update your code for modern Swift. Here's how the declaration should look:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager