Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" getting error when working with coreLocation in swift
import UIKit

import CoreLocation
class WeatherViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var conditionImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var TempratureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CityLabel: UILabel!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var weathermanager = WeatherManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        weathermanager.delegate = self
        searchTextField.delegate = self
       // print("Hii this is console. ")
       
    }
    

}

// MARK: - UITextFieldDelagate

extension WeatherViewController:UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    @IBAction func searchButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        searchTextField.endEditing(true)
        
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       
       searchTextField.endEditing(true)
              
       
    }
    
    
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.text != "" {
           
            return true
        }else{
            textField.placeholder = "Write Valid Location"
            return false
        }
    }
    
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        if let cityname = textField.text {
            weathermanager.fetchWeather(cityname: cityname)
           // CityLabel.text = cityname
        }else{
            print("invalid city name typed")
        }
        
        searchTextField.text = ""
    }
  
}


// MARK: - WeatherManagerDelegate
extension WeatherViewController:WeatherManagerDelegate {
    
    func didupdateWeather(weather:WeatherModel){
        
        //print(weather.temprature)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.TempratureLabel.text = weather.tempratureString
            self.CityLabel.text = weather.cityname
            self.conditionImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: weather.conditionName)
        }
                
        
    }
}

extension WeatherViewController:CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
            let lon = location.coordinate.longitude
            print(lat)
            print(lon)
            weathermanager.fetchWeather( latitute:lat, longitute:lon)
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: any Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}

I want solution for this getting this error again and again Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 (null)"
what's wrong

You should provide more debugging information. At what point do you see the error?  Does your app prompt for location permission successfully? Do you receive a location update? Have you used the debugger to step through your code?

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887820/833395
