# iOS Wikitude SDK crash on exit/reopen app

Tags: ios, jenkins, wikitude

I've developed a simply app for iOS and Augmented Reality (with WikitudeSDK).
All go fine, but when I exit and reopen the app, at times the app crashes with the following message:

Assertion failure in -[WTGCDDriver createSharedContextWithId:], /Users/emperor/Development/Tools/Jenkins/Master/Instance/jobs/architect_sdk_builder/workspace/repositories/ios_core_services/src/Rendering/Driver/WTDriver.mm:71

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: _context'

Have you any idea of this?
Thanks.

Comment: Try this solution it is working in my project : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32082677/3901620

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the OpenGL context is null when you reopen your app; you receive this error because we seem to have forgotten to disable assertions for a public build. So thanks for making us aware of this oversight.

With respect to the actual issue, I cannot provide an answer without having more of an insight into what exactly your app is doing and which version and configuration of the SDK you are using.

I'd therefore like you to create a thread in the Wikitude forums which provides a platform that is better suited for assisting you with this issue than Stack Overflow is.