# iOS 9 Location Update Background task after 3 minutes

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager, background-process

I've been digging into this code which is using a basic timer to check for location updates. I then have it sending lat/lng to a server.

http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7
https://github.com/voyage11/Location

It's working well when plugged in and hooked up through XCode, however when I unplug and take the device mobile, the OS seems to always kill the background thread exactly after 3 minutes. So if I set the timer to run every 30 seconds, I'll get ~6 updates until I bring the app up to the foreground.

I have read that max background execution time is 3 minutes, but as I see it this code is resetting the background task after 1 minute, so I'm not sure why I'm seeing this.

There must be some way around this. Anything I can do here?

EDIT: this helped me: [allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates in CLLocationManager in iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808192/allowsbackgroundlocationupdates-in-cllocationmanager-in-ios9)

Comment: aherrick did you find a solution for this?  I tried the code listed in your edit, setting allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES, but I am still getting terminated after 3 minutes with the background GPS polling.  was there any additional changes you made to get the GPS polling in the background to work?

Comment: Hey! yes actually. So I realized that there isn't a need to background pole. I just simply UIBackgroundModes set to Location. It just works at that point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

se:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
    [self.locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
}
```

This is needed for background location tracking.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, the code at the github repo listed above - https://github.com/voyage11/Location - has recently been updated with a fix for iOS 9, that will allow the GPS to continuously poll in the background without the thread getting terminated after 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into unreliablity problems when running this otherwise excellent library, integrated into other xcode modules in a more sophisticated app, they might look at the initialisation statement for the background task list Id array and consider changing `_bgTaskIdList = [NSMutableArray array]; to _bgTaskIdList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; in BackgroundTaskManager.m`  Until I did this I got unreliable behavious. Sometimes it worked and sometimes I got a stack dump. I found that this was because bgTaskList had been overwritten with other data causing bad access errors.