# Location updates are not delivered on device while application is in background

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, location-services, ios9.1

I'm working on an application that should be able to collect location data while the application is in background.

To allow this, I have done the following:

- In the project settings, under the `Capabilities` tab I have ticked `Location updates`.
  [image]
- I have set the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in the Applications `Info.plist` and have assigned an appropriate string value.
- I have configured an instance of `CLLocationManager` like so:

  - `locationManager.activityType = .Fitness`
  - `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest`
  - `locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false`
- Before beginning location collection I call `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`, I have the appropriate delegate callbacks to handle any error.
- lastly, I call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`

When running the application on the simulator, I get a print out of the location updates, and the application's badge is also updated with the number of locations collected, but when running the applications on an actual device, after sending the app in the background, location updates are shortly stopped from being handled by the app (I know this as the badge stops updating).

Am I missing some sort of device specific configuration?

Comment: I had the same issue for a while and in my case it was because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808192/allowsbackgroundlocationupdates-in-cllocationmanager-in-ios9/30821461#30821461), basically `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` variable is false as default in iOS 9. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ujell thanks! that has solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my setting that works all right when the app is in the background or the device in standby mode:

```
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.activityType = .Other
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

I am also using deferred location updates. In `didUpdateLocations`:

```
if CLLocationManager.deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable() && deferringUpdates == false {
            locationManager.allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled(CLLocationDistanceMax, timeout: deferredLocationTimeout)
            deferringUpdates = true
}
```

and in `didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError`:

```
deferringUpdates = false
```

Comment: Thanks @MirekE, but I don't want to defer location updates. I want to process them in background as they come in.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the capabilities is not enough as of iOS 9. You need to also set `locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true` on your Location Manager before OS can deliver updates to you in the background. It is compulsory to do so according to the documentation. By default it is set to false. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates).