# Delegate method is not called for significant location change when iOS app is in foreground or background

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

In my app I need to get notified when significant change occurs in user's current location so I'm using core location's startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() and handling user's location in

```
locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])  delegate.
```

I'm using Freedrive in Debug>Location so that user's current location keeps on changing. For the first time when I set my class as delegate I receive the delegate call back in locationManager: didUpdateLocations delegate method.

After 1st call this method is never called, I'm not getting why!
I have set proper keys in Info.plist to get Always location permission and grants always permission to the app.

Comment: are you need update location on background or foreground?

Comment: I need to update the location on both background and foreground and I need to achieve it using significant location change @jp_Mob

Comment: are you using  startUpdatingLocation, startUpdatingHeading properties.

Comment: Im using only startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Comment: Do you need to set / did you set Background Modes: location updates in your Xcode settings? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34413018/224334

Comment: @RyanWilcox Yes I Did

Comment: Are you using always authorization?

Comment: Can you show some more code; how you set up,your CLLocationManager and your `didUpdateLocations` method.