# Disabling allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates (CLLocationManager) doesn't work after is was enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

My Application works with continuous background location updates.
Of course it has all the permissions and other stuff like

```
allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

Initially I wanted to **react to** `LowPowerMode` changes while in background using `NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChange` notification. And to disable `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` **to stop updating locations** without calling `stopUpdatingLocation`.

However, I found out that after receiving the notification and setting

```
allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = false
```

in background application is going on working.

So I went farther and identified, that **disabling** `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` even **in foreground** after it was initially set to `true` doesn't work at all. Application continues working in background.

Apple's documentation on the matter

> you use this property to enable and disable the behavior based on your
>   app’s behavior

---

From the CLLocationManager class, description of `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` property

> With UIBackgroundModes set to include "location" in Info.plist, you
>   must also set this property to YES at runtime whenever calling
>   -startUpdatingLocation with the intent to continue in the background. Resetting this property to NO is equivalent to omitting "location"
>   from the UIBackgroundModes value.

[Simple project](https://github.com/Sander-Kornev/LocationTest) on GitHub that shows the behavior I mentioned.

So the question, is it intentional behavior of the property?

Comment: I am finding this as well in iOS 11.  Strangely enough this appears to be working in the simulator but not on an actual device.  I have to restart my app in order for it to take effect, so "toggling" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> When the value of this property is false, apps receive location updates normally while running in either the foreground or ***background based on its current authorization***. Updates stop only when the app is suspended, thereby preventing the app from being woken up to handle those events.[Apple API Discussion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates).

I think the property discussion can solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, this explanation just makes thing worse. In the WWDC 2015, What's new in CoreLocation, they definitely described it as a flag that stops background update when set to false https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/714/?time=505.  Moreover, regarding to my example, if you don't set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to true background update doesn't work. And if you set to true, and then to false, then background update will work. That's the question.

Comment: @Sander,I read your [github sample project](https://github.com/Sander-Kornev/LocationTest),you use the `requestAlwaysAuthorization()`,I think it's the reason, you can use `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` instead,then it will work as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I have to stop and restart location update for allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to take effect when setting it to false if previously has been set to true

```
locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = false
locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Then it will take effect..

Answer (score 0):

Despite it's maybe misleading name, it looks like [`requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization) gives you the behaviour you want (like @zhongwuzw [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710387/588314)).

From the documentation:

> If the user grants “when-in-use” authorization to your app, your app can start most (but not all) location services while it is in the foreground. (Apps cannot use any services that automatically relaunch the app, such as region monitoring or the significant location change service.) **When started in the foreground, services continue to run in the background** if your app has enabled background location updates in the Capabilities tab of your Xcode project. Attempts to start location services while your app is running in the background will fail.

If you need the "always" permission (or the user grants it without you asking for it through the Settings app), I found that stopping and immediately re-starting the location manager forces `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to take effect.